# How to get specific column values when other two columns values are equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get a specific column value when the other 2 columns values are equal, how can I accomplish this?

| user | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mary | 1000 | 1000 |
| jane | 9999 | 2222 |

Let's say the column value that I want to get is 'user'. Expected output is

```
mary
```

Comment: Try this : `df.loc[df['center']==df['right'], 'user']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `DataFrame.query`, although it's not quite its typical use case.

```
>>> df.query('center == right')['user'].iat[0]

'mary'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['center'] == df['right']]['user'][0]
```

```
'mary '
```

OR

```
df[df['center'] == df['right']]
```

```
    user    center  right
0   mary    1000    1000
```

Comment: Technically it's incorrect because `[0]` selects the rows by index labels (i.e. selects the row named `0`) not by position. It works in this specific case because the desired row is the first one. You should change it to `.iloc[0]` for position-based indexing.

Comment: @Rodalm, the result of filtering is a series with an integers as an index (int64Index([0], dtype='int64'), and using [0] is a position based i.e. selects the first row. In case when there are multiple rows are filtered, it will still return the first row because the index is integer based and generated as part of the result set, like  Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64'). Now, Had i defined the labels as part of creating the series, then "[0]" would have selected the row with label [0] as oppose to the first row. this solution is technically correct and produces desired result. Thoughts?

Comment: Using `[0]` is not position based, it's label based. That is what I am trying to say. You can try it yourself with a different example. What if the order of the index is changed? What if 'mary' row is the second row, i.e. index=1? You don't know from the beginning, and your solution wouldn't work in those cases. Test the following `s = pd.Series(['first', 'second'], index=[1, 0]);
print(s, '\n');
print('value [0]:', s[0]);
print('value loc[0]:', s.loc[0]);
print('value iloc[0]:', s.iloc[0])`. What is the output? What can you conclude from that?

Comment: i didn't disagree with what you said the first time. In this particular scenario, the index is auto generated starting from zero. Had the index been assigned, as you suggested, the result would be as you suggested. With auto generated index, 0 will always be the first.  Peace

Comment: the solution works fine in this specific scenario

Comment: Exactly like I said, it only works in this very specific scenario. The index being auto-generated (i.e. being sorted integers) is a necessary condition but not sufficient for your solution to work. I think you are not aware of that. As I said, if the row selected  (i.e. of user 'mary') was the second (i.e. had the index label=1), your solution doesn't work. You can't just assume that the index label of the selected row is 0, like you are doing, you don't know that beforehand. Otherwise what would be the point of the boolean mask?

Comment: If you knew that  the index is 0,  you would just use `df.loc[0, 'user`]` to get `'mary'`, no? But I will not continue this discussion, because its pointless... If you still think your solution is technically correct, it's fine by me

Answer (score 1):

I think @Naveed's answer works perfectly. Another way I would suggest solving the problem is with the '.loc' method.

[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

I would write the code like this:

```markdown
# Defining the filtering condition
fc1 = df['center'] == df['right']

# Applying the filter condition to obtain the value of the desired column
df.loc[fc1, 'user'].values[0]
```

Result:

```markdown
'mary'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['center']==df['right'], 'user'].iloc[0]
```

```
'mary'
```